# Javascript CSS3: Move div container

Tags: javascript, css

I've been messing with this code for awhile now and I'm stuck. I've done a lot of coding by hand but just now ramping up on the new things with HTML5, CSS3, and Javascript.

I'm trying to make a simple menu that slides up and down. I have a div that contains everything. The div has overflow set to hidden so when the menu is out of the viewing box, it can't be seen. It can then animate in and out of the view box.

I've been trying to do it with a Javascript function but it sounds like it's easier to just use CSS3 transitions? Any advice?

My Javascript code is below. I can't quite figure out how to do it with CSS3 transitions. Any advice would be much appreciated.

Html

```
<header>
<nav>
<div id="mobileMenu" class="mobileMenu">
    <div id="mobileMenuWrapper" class="mobileMenuWrapper">
        <div style="height: 100px; width: 100%;">
            <div style="height: 100px; width: 100%; background-color: black; color: white;">
            Menu option<br>Menu option<br>Menu option
            </div>
        </div>
        <div style="position: relative; height: 50px; width: 100%; left: 50px;">
            <div style="height: 50px; width: 125px; background-color: black; color: white;    text-align: center;"><a href="javascript:moveMenuDown();">Menu</a></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</nav>
</header>
```

Javascript

```
var startPosition = -100;
var endPosition = 0;
var speed = 2;

function moveMenuDown(){
    // Get the element
    menu = document.getElementById("mobileMenuWrapper");

    // Grab the element's current CSS top position
    currentPosition = Number(menu.style.top.substr(0,(menu.style.top.length-2)));

    // Compare the position and move it
    if(currentPosition <= endPosition){

        // I'm stuck about the line below...how can I attach a CSS3 transition here? Or should I?
        menu.style.MozTransition = ???;

        // Here's my original code where I move the element manually
        menu.style.top = (currentPosition + speed) + 'px';
        moveMenuDown();
    }else{

    }
}
```

Updated entire HTML/CSS/JavaScript

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<title>Menu test</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />

<style>
    .mobileMenu {
        position: absolute;
        height: 150px;
        width: 250px;
        top: 0px;
        left: 50px;
        overflow: hidden;
    }

    #mobileMenuWrapper {
    margin-top:-100px;
       transition: margin-top 0.5s ease;
    }

    #mobileMenuWrapper.show {
     margin-top:0px;
    }
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function moveMenuDown(){

        menu = document.getElementById("mobileMenuWrapper hide");

        if(menu.className=="mobileMenuWrapper hide"){
            menu.className = menu.className.replace('hide','show');
        }else{
            menu.className = "mobileMenuWrapper hide";
        }
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>

<header>
<nav>
<div id="mobileMenu" class="mobileMenu">
    <div id="mobileMenuWrapper" class="mobileMenuWrapper hide">
        <div style="height: 100px; width: 100%;">
            <div style="height: 100px; width: 100%; background-color: black; color: white;">
            Menu option<br>Menu option<br>Menu option
            </div>
        </div>
        <div style="position: relative; height: 50px; width: 100%; left: 50px;">
            <div style="height: 50px; width: 125px; background-color: black; color: white; text-align: center;"><a href="javascript:moveMenuDown();">Menu</a></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</nav>
</header>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You should just use CSS completely. Why would you use a JS script to add a CSS transition in this case? My advice: get rid of this JS.

Comment: I wasn't sure. I'm new to CSS3 transitions and how they work. I'll research it and figure them out. Thanks.

Comment: @flasshy, could you post current html/css? How you activate slide up/down? (on click, or on hover)?

Comment: I'll add the html. Sorry I didn't at first. I just call this Javascript function onclick.

Comment: My question now is for the CSS3 transition, do I make two CSS3 classes for the container? One is the start position and one is the end position with transition in that class? I'm digging around online to figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML: one additional class:

```
<header>
<nav>
<div id="mobileMenu" class="mobileMenu">
    <div id="mobileMenuWrapper" class="mobileMenuWrapper hide">
        <div style="height: 100px; width: 100%;">
            <div style="height: 100px; width: 100%; background-color: black; color: white;">
            Menu option<br>Menu option<br>Menu option
            </div>
        </div>
        <div style="position: relative; height: 50px; width: 100%; left: 50px;">
            <div style="height: 50px; width: 125px; background-color: black; color: white;    text-align: center;"><a id="move" href="javascript:moveMenuDown();">Menu</a></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</nav>
</header>
```

CSS: (very simple)

```
#mobileMenuWrapper{
margin-top:-100px; 
   transition: margin-top 0.5s ease;   
}

#mobileMenuWrapper.show{
 margin-top:0px;   
}
```

*just added class and transition.

JS, much simpler:

```
function moveMenuDown(){


 menu = document.getElementById("mobileMenuWrapper");
    if(menu.className=="mobileMenuWrapper hide"){
  menu.className = menu.className.replace('hide','show');
    }
    else {
         menu.className = "mobileMenuWrapper hide";  

    }
   }
```

('toggle' functionality added)

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8u0eka5x/

Comment: Thank you so much! I'm going to try this method but one question, why did you use margin-top instead of top?

Comment: Because of position:relative (default position, don't know your CSS structure -> for demo purposes - this works fine, top not so fine)... Edited: http://jsfiddle.net/8u0eka5x/1/ 'top' version...

Comment: I was using position: absolute because I will need this container to overlap over elements. If I use relative, it'll push other elements around, right? I know that's a difficult question to ask when you can't see my whole html. I'll figure it out. I appreciate your help!

Comment: I'm pretty sure I just added all of your improvements and I think I get how this works...but for some reason it's not working for me...

Comment: I added my updated code to my main question. Your JSFiddles work fine for me but when I put it in my code, something is awry...

Comment: @flasshy, you made one error in js: menu = document.getElementById("mobileMenuWrapper"); NOT what is currently there... and, all works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/shr794np/ :)

Comment: Oops. Perfect! I really, really appreciate your help! If I can, to make sure I get how CSS3 transitions work and so I don't keep bugging everyone all the time...I define one class with the default styles with transition attributes then whatever transition I called out in this styles will occur any time that attribute is changed. Is that about right?