# What's the name of this CSS3 syntax?

Tags: css

I'm asking this question because I'm trying to understand the CSS3 style changes that make this code work: [Javascript CSS3: Move div container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26701254/javascript-css3-move-div-container)

Quick question because I don't know where else to ask...what's the below called? I want to learn more about it but not sure what it's called.

Is the "state" part of className some sort of CSS3 state...or something?

```
<style>
  #className {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100px;
    transition: height 1s ease;
  }

  #className.state {
    height: 25px;
  }
</style>
```

Comment: Why not read the specification yourself? http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/

Comment: Because I wanted to read about this specific syntax and didn't know what it was called. If I knew what it was called, I would have gladly went and researched it by name. At the moment, I don't have the time to read the entire specification just to find this specific case. Now, I will read the specification about selectors. Thank you for your help.

Comment: You need only skim the table of contents to find the relevant portion. Or look at the Wikipedia page.

Comment: Why did you even respond if you're just going to be unhappy about it? Sheesh. Other users didn't find it that difficult to be helpful.

Comment: I'm trying to teach you how to solve problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is called CSS Selectors and there is nothing specific with CSS3 in this code.

Dot (.) is `class` selector. You can have multiple elements with same styles, and this is where you use class names.

Hash (#) is `id` selector. This selector only applies to a single element. In most cases you should be avoiding to use `id`s for CSS selectors unless you really need it. This is just a suggestion.

One selector after another, without comma (,) selects the element inside the particular element.

In this case

```
#className.state
```

Selects all classes with name `state` inside the id `className`.

**Edit**

Given the HTML:

```
<div id="mobileMenuWrapper">
    <div class="hide">
        Content of the element            
    </div>
</div>
```

And the following CSS selector:

```
#mobileMenuWrapper.hide{
    margin-top:0px;
}
```

Element with the class name `hide` will be selected. It will take the style. Its margin from top will be 0.

However, something like this is applying multiple classes to a signle element. And it is another story.

```
<div class="mobileMenuWrapper hide"></div>
```

Anyways, so get a better understanding of all there, you still need to read something like [this](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/selector.html) or [this one](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/the-30-css-selectors-you-must-memorize--net-16048). At least a quick scan.

Comment: Hmm. Okay. I'm trying to understand the "show" and "hide" parts of the CSS in the solution for this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26701254/javascript-css3-move-div-container . Are those "show" and "hide" attributes not a specific CSS3 thing?

Comment: no it's not. it is saying "select class `show` inside the id `mobileMenuWrapper`". class `show` is not in the html by default, but it is being added with javascript in this case.

Comment: So, in that code, when the class on the HTML element is "mobileMenuWrapper hide"...does that mean the class assigned is "#mobileMenuWrapper.hide"?

Comment: Excellent! I get it now. It's applying two classes to the same element. I wasn't even aware that was possible. I thought each HTML element could only have one class at a time. Interesting. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

It must be a class name.For example you can have an item with an Id to style only an item but you want to have some common styles with other elements

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's called a class.  Classes are rules that apply to multiple elements, while ids apply only to specific elements.

A class selector looks like: .

A id selector looks like: #

An input element could have a specific Id: `<input type"text" id="monthly_cost"/>`

*Note that no other elements can have the same id.  It causes an HTML error.*

For multiple elements, you use the class selector: `<h1 class="blue_heading">`

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Its called CSS Selector.
You can read about it here: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp

Comment: Can you include an example of a selector, since link only answers on SO are discouraged?